# How can i manage my Ble connection?

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have 3 `Activity`s: `Activity` A,`Activity` B,`Activity` C.

B and C is intent from A;

I create connnect like:

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
```

I know that the number of `BluetoothGatt` is up to 6.

1.Every `Activity` may create several `BluetoothGatt`s.

2.Two `Activity`s may connect same device.

If i put all `BluetoothGatt`s in A, A maybe kill by system when I intent to B.

If i put gat in `Activity` that create it,i should add listener in every `Activity` and I dont know whether a device is connected in other `Activity`.

Is there a function to get all `BluetoothGatt`s ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a Utils/Manager class that servers as a single point through which you can manage connections to different devices. All your activities in your app can make use of methods from this class to obtain a GattConnection or perform any other operation.